# How can I run one spec 100 times using the command line?

Tags: ruby, capybara, intermittent-failures, rspec

We're getting intermittent failures.

Hope can I run one test 100 times to see how 'stable' it is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using [zsh shell](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh):

```
repeat 10 { command }
```

On basic shell:

```
for _ in {1..10} do command; done
```

If you can run the tests in parallel, you can use the [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel command ::: {1..1000}
```

Tutorial videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Text tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Your test framework probably has some functionality to rerun failed tests. Behat, for instance, has a [--rerun option](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/6.cli.html).

Answer (score 2):

Create a script in your home directory, e.g.

```
  $ cat run_spec_100_times.sh

    cd ~/eq/lynx
    for i in `seq 1 100`;
      do
        rspec spec/features/survey_spec.rb
      done
    cd ~
```

Modify the script to be executable with `chmod +x run_spec_100_times.sh`

The use it with `. run_spec_100_times.sh`